# My Nexus 7 is dead, any suggestion?

Tags: charging, nexus-7

My Nexus 7 died. I didn't see it happening. My son was playing, went to school and left it charging. At night it didn't turn on anymore. The screen is black.

I've followed the [Asus instructions](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2668668?hl=en&ref_topic=3415522). This [answer](http://androidforums.com/nexus-7-2012/594627-nexus-7-dead-wont-charge-3.html#post5498724) says to disconnect the battery. Any other tip? Nexus isn't officially sold in my country (Brazil). I'm afraid I won't get be able to use the warranty.

Since the last update, I've noticed some hiccups. Maybe it was due to excess of running applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to buy a Galaxy Tab.

My Nexus is dead. Asus not even accepts it to make a diagnostic. The "global" warranty is not valid in Brazil. By a better quality product from a company that respect their users.

Answer (score 1):

Hold the `Pwr & Vol-` **60** seconds. Release, Press and hold power button for up to 10 seconds. Release.

If this does not work, it is fairly easy to remove the back cover and detatch the battery.

Comment: Is there any difference if I detach the plug from the battery side of the board size? (I don't know if I can do it from the battery side).